# R: Scraped data will not format to text seen in colsole

Tags: r, list, web-scraping, geolocation, format

After scraping and parsing data I got the list bellow:

```
latitude_list <- xpathSApply(PARSED, "//meta[@itemprop='latitude']")

> lat
[[1]]
<meta content="37.974807" itemprop="latitude"/> 

[[2]]
<meta content="37.9830836" itemprop="latitude"/> 

[[3]]
<meta content="37.9643196" itemprop="latitude"/> 

[[4]]
<meta content="37.974807" itemprop="latitude"/>
```

I want to just get the coordinate numbers , (i.e. 37.974807,37.9830836,37.9643196,37.974807)

Whenever I convert list to try to extract what I am want.  I get

For example:

```
> latitude_list <- as.character(latitude_list )
> latitude_list 
[1] "<pointer: 0x000000001c4c5e00>" "<pointer: 0x000000001c52b970>" "    <pointer: 0x000000001c52bcf0>" "<pointer: 0x000000001c52d570>"
```

I have no idea why I am getting this text. Can someone please explain what is going on?

Comment: Well, you only have nodes not values. Perhaps actually asking `xpathSApply` for the values might help: `xpathSApply(PARSED, "//meta[@itemprop='latitude']", xmlValue)`

Comment: Take a look at the rvest package.  The html_attr function should do the trick.

Comment: Strangley, with `xpathSApply(PARSED, "//meta[@itemprop='latitude']", xmlValue)` I get `"" "" "" ""`.  @hrbrmstr

Comment: The `html_attr` function will not accept lists.  Unfortunately that leaves me stuck with the same problem. @Dave2e

Comment: Use `xmlGetAttr, "latitude"` instead. I overlooked the fact that you wanted attributes. But this is also a clear indication you should spend some time practicing XML/HTML scraping operations more in R and possibly even how XML is structured. Even a rudimentary poking at the examples under `help("xpathSApply")` would have shown you how to get to the data you wanted.

Comment: @hrbrmstr  Thank you, this worked. You are correct, I need to spend more time practicing XML/HTML.  This is actually my first attempt to do so.